# The resource owner or authorization server denied the request

Tags: php, ios, laravel, api

I have an iPhone application which uses Laravel for its back-end, it must be published in app store, but app store rejected the app because they have the following error:

> The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException(code: 9): The
>   resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at
>   /var/www/mednfit/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:205)

But I don't have this error. What does this mean?

Comment: first check api in postman if you get correct response then its your device error ,you have not set required attributes or token correctly

Answer (score 37):

This exception related to **expired access token**.

You can add `\League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::class` to your `$dontReport` array in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. This will, however, prevent logging of all `OAuthServerException` exceptions, even those not related to your expired access token.

**Source:** [Laracasts: Error Log Problems When Using Laravel Passport for User Login AuthenticationError Log Problems When Using Laravel Passport for User Login Authentication](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-log-problems-when-using-laravel-passport-for-user-login-authentication?page=1#reply=389574)

Comment: Thanks... Although I'm still getting exception log after added `OAuthServerException::class` to `$dontReport` array. But, solution from Laracasts really solve the problem. Works on Laravel 5.5.

Comment: If someone get the issue even after this modification please check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-log-problems-when-using-laravel-passport-for-user-login-authentication?page=1#reply=389574

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me in **Laravel 9**

Put this into your ***app/Exceptions/Handler.php***

```
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (\League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException $e) {
        if($e->getCode() == 9)
            return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error message as you while logging in still ok. You can try this in `composer.json`

```
"laravel/passport": "9.0.0",
"lcobucci/jwt": "3.4.5",
"league/oauth2-server": "8.1.3",
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why this solves anything?

Answer (score 0):

One of reason for "The resource owner or authorization server denied the request" is `client_id` & `clientSecret` which you pass it to backend is not exists in `oauth_clients` table in database, you must first verify that these data is correct and exists in Laravel database

Answer (score -7):

juste run on prod

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should suggest that without explaining what those command does. Especially given the fact that you said _just run on prod_....