# Laravel Api Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

**Config:**

Laravel 8

Passport 10.3

PHP 7.4.23

CentOs 8.3

***Problem:***

I have a api rest working on Windows (local), in Postman generate token (/api/login) and use Bearer token to list username (/user), no error, its ok.

When i make same process in WebServer online (linux), token ok, no problem but when i get this token and try get username (or other url...) i get error:

> Unauthenticated

**storage/log/laravel.log:**

> ERROR: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. {"exception":"[object] (League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException(code: 9): The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. at /var/www/website/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/Exception/OAuthServerException.php:243)

**I try:**

- \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
- optimize:clear
- SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

and a lot others...

**api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(config('auth.token_expiration.token')));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(config('auth.token_expiration.refresh_token')));
}
```

**config/auth.php**

```
'api' => [
        'driver'   => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash'     => false,
 ],
```

Anyone can help how to resolve?

Comment: try this : php artisan passport:purge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57869374/6711823

Comment: Amir Kaftari, purged only revoked items and items expired for more than seven days, i try, same error..

Comment: Ramil Huseynov i don´t wanna hide report, i want a solution to resolve problem.

Comment: RESOLVED: change composer.json passport version to 10.4 and run composer update laravel/passport -W

Comment: @Kin did you find a solution for a newer version of Passport? Facing exact same problem on our prod env

Comment: Sorry @megachill, I haven't tried to update. But if you are starting a new application, you might want to use Sanctum

Comment: @Kin it sort of self fixed itself... turns out it might have been caching on some end. Anyways, after we cleared everything and re-deployed it was all good again ./shrug